# Validate an validation?

Tags: javascript, html

It works almost perfect, but i dont get why this code had to validate the 0 or my 10

I am doing a validation, that if the counter reaches 0 the button is deactivated. But for some reason, in the console and in the html it shows 0, but it makes me click once more to be able to deactivate the button. I'm not understanding what's going on. Exactly the same thing happens with the other stop, when you reach 10 you have to click again on the add button to deactivate the button.

```
const botonmas = document.getElementById("mas")
botonmas.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    increme(contador)
})
const botonmenoss = document.getElementById("menos")
botonmenoss.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    decre(contador)
})
const prodcSelct = document.getElementById("productosSelec")
let contador = 0
function increme(){
    if(contador<10){
        contador++
        botonmenoss.disabled = false
    }else if(contador == 10){
        botonmas.disabled = true
    }
    prodcSelct.innerHTML = contador 
    console.log(contador)
}

function decre(){
    if(contador>0){
        contador--
        botonmas.disabled = false
    }else if(contador == 0){
        botonmenoss.disabled = true
    }
    prodcSelct.innerHTML = contador 
    console.log(contador)
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="./contador2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <p id="precio"></p>
        <p id="stock"></p>
        <p id="productosSelec"></p>
        <div>
            <button id="menos">-</button>
            <button id="mas">+</button>
            <button id="comprar">Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

i expect when it marks 0, the botton get disabled

Comment: Your code checks to see if `contador` is less than 10 or greater than 0. When it is 9, it is less than 10, so you increment `contador` to 10, keep the button (increment) enabled, and update the field. Same for decrement. Your `if` checks happen *before* you change the counter.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Pointy in comments allow me to see what is wrong

In the validation, i am changing the counter after the if checks. So correctly its

```
function increme(){
    contador++
    if(contador<10){
        botonmenoss.disabled = false
    }else if(contador == 10){
        botonmas.disabled = true
    }
    prodcSelct.innerHTML = contador 
    console.log(contador)
}
```